# Reading from a blog in a custom web part using SharePoint 2013

Tags: sharepoint, blogs, web-parts, sharepoint-2013

Does anyone know if there is a way to access blog posts in a custom web part using SharePoint 2013?  I've accessed a list like this:

```
SPSite site = new SPSite("http://site/sites/publish/Lists");
SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb();
SPList list = web.Lists["Research Publications"];
```

but I don't see a SPBlog or similar object for blogs.

Answer (score 0):

You have Permission to access?

You are in a sandbox?

Sandbox dont reat external bases..

Comment: I have full access to everything and the web part is deployed as a farm solution.

Comment: Then i dont can help you :(

Answer (score 0):

Oh, duh.  The actual posts in a blog are simply a list and I can connect to the blog directly with SPSite since it is a subsite...so this code grabs the posts from my "announcements" blog subsite.

```
SPSite site = new SPSite("http://site/sites/publish/announcements");
SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb();
SPList posts = web.Lists["Posts"];
```